# Swift: Covariant overrides?

Tags: swift, covariance

is there any way of supporting covariant return types in Swift?

For example, I'd like to support the following scenario:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog : Animal{}
class Cat : Animal {}

class AnimalResidency{
    func getAllAnimals() -> Array<Animal> {
        return []
    }
}
class Cattery : AnimalResidency{
    override func getAllAnimals() -> Array<Cat> {
        return [Cat(), Cat()]
    }
}
class DogKennel : AnimalResidency {
    override func getAllAnimals() -> Array<Dog> {
        return [Dog(), Dog(), Dog(), Dog()]
    }
}
```

The overridden func produces a compiler error because the overrides signature doesn't exactly match the base definition, even though  it's clear to see the contents returned by the override would still meet the contract of the base definition.

Is there any way for me to achieve the above? I'd even appreciate an answer for Swift 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's necessary to do *exactly* what you ask - i.e. *override* `getAllAnimals` rather than overload it. Using generics is a possible solution - see if this works for you:

```
class Animal { var description: String { return "Animal" } }
class Dog : Animal { override var description: String { return "Dog" } }        
class Cat : Animal { override var description: String { return "Cat" } }

class AnimalResidency<T: Animal>{
    func getAllAnimals<T>() -> Array<T> {
        return []
    }
}

class Cattery : AnimalResidency<Cat> {
    func getAllAnimals() -> Array<Cat> {
        return [Cat()]
    }
}

class DogKennel : AnimalResidency<Dog> {
    func getAllAnimals() -> Array<Dog> {
        return [Dog(), Dog()]
    }
}

let c = Cattery()
c.getAllAnimals().first?.description // "Cat"
let d = DogKennel()
d.getAllAnimals().first?.description // "Dog"
```

My own thinking would not have used two parallel class hierarchies, however, but to try something more like this...

```
class Animal {
    var description: String { return "Animal" }
    required init() {}
}
class Dog : Animal {
    override var description: String { return "Dog" }
}
class Cat : Animal {
    override var description: String { return "Cat" }
}

extension Animal {
    class func home() -> [Animal] {
        return [self.init()]
    }
}

let c = Cat.home().first?.description // "Cat"
let d = Dog.home().first?.description // "Dog"
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift use protocol oriented paradigm. So based on you're request. It is better to use protocols and PATs in you're case.

[What are PATs.](https://www.natashatherobot.com/swift-what-are-protocols-with-associated-types/)

```
protocol BaseProtocol {
    //PAT's
    typealias ReturnType: BaseType
    func someFunction() -> ReturnType
}

class SomeClass : BaseProtocol {
    func someFunction() -> BaseType {  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't see any evidence of covariance in the example you've posted. Could you point out where the covariance applies please?

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, the signatures must be exactly the same.

But you can use `[Base]` as return type in your `Derived`-class.

```
class Base {
    var a = "A" //just a property to check if you can access properties of this class

    var test: [Base] {
        return [self]
    }

    func test2() -> [Base] {
        return [self]
    }
}

class Derived: Base {
    var b = "B" //just a property to check if you can access properties of this class

    override var test: [Base] {
        return [self]
    }

    override func test2() -> [Base] {
        return [self]
    }
}
```

You could either use `test2()` or `test` (a computed property).

**Before you can access a property of an object stored in the array, you have to cast it as** `Derived`**.**

```
let d = Derived()
let dArray = d.test2()

print((dArray[0] as! Derived).b) //Prints "B"
```

Comment: This approach breaks down on the print line where you have to force cast to `Derived` to access `b`. OP would like the derived classes to return specific types derived from super's return type so casting isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in FelixSFD's answer your aim conflicts with interface-oriented paradigm. `HeadOffice` should use interface of `Office`, ex:

```
let staff: [Office] = [Office(), HeadOffice()]
for person in staff {
    // every `person` responds to `Office` interface
}
```

In your case I would propose to use generics because they are designed for such kind of things:

```
func getAllStaff<T>(obj: T) -> Array<T?> {
    return [obj]
}
```

You could also implement `getAllStaff` as method of class, depending on your needs...